# Memory leak in virtual environment

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, memory, memory-leaks, virtualenv

I have a numpy array of `size=(200, 76, 101)`; each of its items is the result of an integral computed numerically, through a complicated function that I will call `fun` (it involves using `scipy.integrate.quad`, and it imports scipy inside of it, if it matters), using a for loop:

```
a = np.array(size, 'float64')
for i in range(76):
    for j in range(101):
        for k in range(200):
            a[k,i,j] = fun(parameters[i, j]) # this is the integrating function
np.savez('file.npz', a)
```

So, when I run this thing, in a python 3 virtual environment (as well as a python 2 v.env.), I see that the memory usage is increasing steadily, until the program is killed; if I run it outside the v.env., the memory usage remains constant, as expected.

What should I know about virtual environments that is not being told to me?

Comment: What happens if you replace each `range()` with `xrange()` for python 2?

Comment: I made `from builtins import range`

Comment: There is also `xrange` in builtins module. The reason I asked for trying it is the different approach of `xrange`. It returns a tuple-like object unlike `range` returning a list.